# how and where to do following job

Tags: android

Can you tell me how and where to do following job according to http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html :

With an Android-powered device, you can develop and debug your Android applications just as you would on the

emulator. Before you can start, there are just a few things to do:
1.Verify that your application is "debuggable" in your manifest or build.gradle file. 
In the build file, make sure the debuggable property in the debug build type is set to true. The build type property

```
overrides the manifest setting. 
android {
    uildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
```

In the AndroidManifest.xml file, add android:debuggable="true" to the  element.

Answer (score 0):

If your looking to test your app on an actual device make sure to enable debugging on your phone. To do this you generally follow the following steps:

1. Open the 'Settings' on your phone
2. Open 'About phone'
3. Click multiple (about 7) times on Build number, a dialog will show up informing you that you are now a developer.
4. Go back to 'Settings' and click on 'Developer options'
5. Enable USB debugging

You also need to allow your computer to trust your device. This you do in the dialog that pops up on your phone, after connecting with USB.